# Where are epitopes located on HLA molecules?

Tags: biochemistry, immunology, medicine, autoimmune

Normally HLA molecules present cellular and extra cellular proteins to the immune system; presumably the proteins in this case are where antibody /t-cells etc bind.

But when an organ is transplanted to a HLA incompatible recipient, are they binding to the HLA molecule itself? If antibody response was reliant on the proteome expressed in and around the cell HLA incompatibility wouldn't be such a problem.

What about auto immune diseases?

Comment: Your question is both unclear and quite broad. *`"presumably the proteins in this case are where antibody /t-cells etc bind."`* Please expand on this, I really don't know what you mean. *`"But when an organ is transplanted to a HLA incompatible recipient, are they binding to the HLA molecule itself?"`* What do you mean by *`they`*? *`"If antibody response was reliant on the proteome expressed in and around the cell HLA incompatibility wouldn't be such a problem."`* Why do you think that? *`"What about auto immune diseases?"`* What about them? Please [edit] your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @MattDMo the question is pretty clear, he's using correct terminology for the topic

Comment: @iayork I'm an immunologist, and I don't really think it's clear at all. In the first sentence, the OP is mixing antibody and HLA/TCR epitopes, and it's not clear which is being discussed where. *`"are they binding..."`* is definitely unclear, I don't know what "they" is. I don't understand the reasoning behind the 2nd sentence in the 2nd paragraph. Finally, the last sentence is completely apropos of nothing - what *about* autoimmunity? The whole thing is unclear and far too broad.

Comment: Seems clear to me (also an immunologist).  He's asking how transplant non-self MHC is recognized (peptide dependent or not) and how autoimmune MHC is recognized (peptide dependent or not).  Good questions, if rather basic, and worth addressing.

Comment: @mattdmo you rightly picked up on my confusion. I work with hla antibody, but am a mathematician by background. Most of the material I can find doesn't seem to make clear where the epitopes are located. I am not sure if hla antibody bind to the same epitopes as the t cells or to others entirety. So if you want more clarity, I am interested in the locations of the binding sites of either.

Comment: @Abijah HLA antibody, meaning antibody that binds HLA? Mostly it binds in regions other than where the peptide epitope is, but there are a handful that bind to the combination of peptide epitope plus HLA, and therefore recognize only the specific combination of HLA plus peptide epitope

Comment: Thanks so much- I think that finally makes sense! Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T cells in a graft see both non-self peptides associated with the non-self HLA molecules, and can also see the non-self HLA molecules regardless of peptide. (MHC is a broader term than HLA, and I will use MHC here.)

> Surface expression of CD4 or CD8 is commonly used to identify T-cell subsets that recognize antigen presented by class II MHC or class I MHC, respectively. This holds true for T cells that respond to allogeneic MHC molecules that are **directly recognized** as foreign, as well as peptides from allogeneic MHC molecules that are indirectly presented by self MHC molecules.

--[Contrasting Alloreactive CD4+ and CD8+ T Cells: There's More to It Than MHC Restriction](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1034/j.1600-6143.2003.00036.x/full)

Recall that as T cells mature in the thymus, they undergo negative selection such that those T cells that spontaneously recognize self MHC molecules are deleted, but there's also positive selection that ensures the T cells can recognize MHC features in general. That leaves many T cells that could spontaneously recognize slightly different MHC molecules (i.e. non-self) that are not deleted. That means that in a transplant, there are a large number of T cells that can recognize the non-self MHC in a non-peptide-dependent manner.  There's also a much smaller number that can interact with the non-self-MHC but only in a peptide-dependent manner; this is just by chance, in that that particular T cell receptor happened to have the shape that sees that non-self-MHC and the peptide.

As for autoimmunity, that's all peptide-dependent, as far as we know, barring some of the really horrendous infant-onset autoimmunities that result from improper T cell maturation in the thymus.